# How to urlize a link in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user defined external URL that I'd like to turn into a link by using something similar to Django's `urlize` filter. How might one go about doing that?

I just need something to add in the preceding `http://` or whatever if it's lacking.

Unless I missed it, `link_to` doesn't seem to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of solutions:

- create a helper `urlize(url)` that adds `http://` if it's missing
- override the url getter on your model to add the `http://`
- add a before_save callback in your model to add the `http://` to the url, thus making sure that you have a valid url in your db

Personally, I just have some validations that check that the url entered is valid. Here, I would use the 3rd option.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple helper method to prepend an http prefix if needed:

```
def url_with_protocol(url)
  /^http/.match(url) ? url : "http://#{url}"
end

> url_with_protocol("google.com")
=> "http://google.com"

> url_with_protocol("http://google.com")
=> "http://google.com"

> url_with_protocol("https://google.com")
=> "https://google.com"
```